# VS Code - Permission denied writing to a file

Tags: html, windows, networking, web, visual-studio-code

I installed an extension for creating notes and gave it a path for storing them in my vscode folder which is in program files, but vscode shows there is no permission to write in that folder. How can I fix it?

Comment: Tried to open vs code in admin mode?

Comment: Yay, it's working now! I have pinned my vscode to the task bar, is there any solution to open it in admin mode from there by default?

Comment: Google it, I found this:
https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-run-programs-as-administrator-in-windows-10-3632744/

Comment: doing it already... thx for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Open your editor as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

**Launch VS Code.**
Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.
Then open terminal and type this command "sudo code"

Answer (score 0):

In unix, it can be done by changing directory ownership to `$USER`

```bash
chown $USER /directory
```

That's all!